# New Install 1204 error "OUT OF RANGE" black screen with cursor and dead

Tags: system-installation

Installed first time with Windows 7 - on reboot got error "OUT OF RANGE" black screen with cursor and dead.
Installed again and wiped Windows 7 off and still get same message.  Will not reboot or respond in any way.
Runs real good from CD but not installation.
Help!

Comment: Do you seen anything else first? Does pressing ALT-CTL-F2 display anything on your monitor? I expect that the message you are seeing is being generated by your monitor because it isn't compatible with what Ubuntu erroneously thinks it can do. You could also try another computer monitor. (There are other things to try, too, but they would be easier to carry out if you could get to the point where you could communicate with the new Ubuntu install somehow.)

Comment: I should have asked above--what kind of monitor and what kind of graphics do you have on your computer?

Comment: I suspect that this is happening in the GRUB boot loader rather than once Ubuntu has booted. What happens if you press `Enter` when you see the `OUT OF RANGE` message? Does that make your Ubuntu system boot?

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is a high likelihood this is being caused by this bug, given that Krzysztof Pyrzyk stated he has an old nvidia card and is getting the same issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173/+bug/948053

I reckon the reason that the livecd worked and your install didn't is that the installer installed the nvidia_current driver for the install but ran the nouveau driver for the livecd.

You can diasble the nvidia_current driver if you can get to a terminal (ctrl-alt-f1) and type this. On reboot this should enable the nouveau driver.

```
sudo jockey-text -d xorg:nvidia_current
```

Older nvidia graphics card run better on the 173 and 96 branches of the nvidia drivers, but neither is currently available on 12.04. However 173 is available from nvidia here: ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.35/ you would need to execute the .run file, however I wouldn't recommend it as it means every kernel update will break it :( and you will need to build the driver again.